# linux df shows old mounts

Tags: linux, mount, cifs

The df command shows old cifs mounts which aren´t existend anymore. The only active mount is

```
"//***/HR-Backup"
```

The system is debian wheezy. How can I get rid of the old entries, and why are they showing up?

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             29657164   2132588  26018068   8% /
tmpfs                   517208         0    517208   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                    512764        92    512672   1% /dev
tmpfs                   517208         0    517208   0% /dev/shm
//***/he-backup$/
                 503313404 396248316 107065088  79% /mnt/backup
//***/Report-Calls-Redmine$/
                 292415096  67284924 225130172  24% /mnt/reporting
//***/he-backup$/
                 503313404 396248316 107065088  79% /mnt/backup
//***/Report-Calls-Redmine$/
                 292415096  67284924 225130172  24% /mnt/reporting
//***/he-backup$/
                 503313404 396248316 107065088  79% /mnt/backup
//***/Report-Calls-Redmine$/
                 292415096  67284924 225130172  24% /mnt/reporting
//***/he-backup$/
                 503313404 396248316 107065088  79% /mnt/backup
//***/Report-Calls-Redmine$/
                 292415096  67284924 225130172  24% /mnt/reporting
//***/he-backup$/
                 503313404 396248316 107065088  79% /mnt/backup
//***/Report-Calls-Redmine$/
                 292415096  67284924 225130172  24% /mnt/reporting
//***/he-backup$/
                 503313404 396248316 107065088  79% /mnt/backup
//***/Report-Calls-Redmine$/
                 292415096  67284924 225130172  24% /mnt/reporting
//***/he-backup$/
                 503313404 396248316 107065088  79% /mnt/backup
//***/Report-Calls-Redmine$/
                 292415096  67284924 225130172  24% /mnt/reporting
//***/Report-Calls-Redmine$/
                 292415096  67284924 225130172  24% /mnt/reporting
//***/he-backup$/
                 503313404 396248316 107065088  79% /mnt/backup
//***/HR-Backup
                 503313404 396248316 107065088  79% /mnt/backup
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
umount /mnt/backup
```

for all of them. I guess they're somehow still mounted when df displays them. What does

```
mount
```

display?

Comment: mount says, they are all mounted, but that is impossible, because most of them would be mounted on the same folder.

Comment: What happens when you try to unmount them?

Comment: When I unmount /mnt/backup, //***/HR-Backup is gone and there is again the old //***/HR-Backup mounted. And so is /mnt/reporting, but I cant unmount the old mounts.

Comment: Any error message? What happens when you try umount //***/he-backup$/

Comment: OK, thx. This umount command worked. I executed again and again...
Now, everything is how it should be :)